# blurry image in texture paint

Tags: texture-painting

when I use a stencil image in texture paint the image applied to the model blurs.
the same happens with stroke : anchored .
I have already increased the resolution of the model image and the stencil image has a 2K resolution.

is there any configuration to do?

---

the image on the left and the image applied to the model on the right.
[image]

Comment: maybe switch the Image Texture from Linear to Closest?

Comment: did not solve .

Comment: Even with closest it's blurry? Hm ... Share your simplified blend just with issue. Thanks ... Don't forget to pack stencil image.

Comment: What does the image result look like in 2d editor versus the 3d view? Is mipmapping turned off for viewport?

Comment: I turned it off and it didn't work. is the mipmap found in texture properties ?

Comment: How big is the image for the model and what does the UV map looks like? If the UV island for the inner area of this pan(?) is fairly small then a 2k high-res stencil helps not much.

Comment: I should have specified - what does the painting result look like in the 2d editor versus the 3d viewport? Mipmapping affects the viewport result appearance but the 2d editor should show the correct pixels without filtering.

Comment: the sharpness of the texture has to do with the subdivision of the model ?

Comment: Please share your file with textures packed ... To avoid a lot of guessing. Thank you ... BTW Blunder's comment sounds to me right.